# failed to load tmx file in cocos2d-JS

Tags: cocos2d-js

When I load the tmx file, I got this **error**:

> Uncaught Error: Please load the resource first: res/map.tmx

```js
//app.js
var HelloWorldLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
    sprite:null,
    ctor:function () {
        this._super();
        var size = cc.winSize;
        var map = new cc.TMXTiledMap(res.map_tmx);
        this.addChild(map);
        return true;
    }
});

var HelloWorldScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter:function () {
        this._super();
        var layer = new HelloWorldLayer();
        this.addChild(layer);
    }
});
```

```js
//resource.js
var res = {
    map_tmx: 'res/map.tmx',
    mobset_png: 'res/mobset.png'
};

var g_resources = [];
for (var i in res) {
    g_resources.push(res[i]);
}
```

What's **wrong** with it. And how can I figure it out!!!

Answer (score 0):

please load png file first and then the tmx file. when you load the tmx file, it searches for the png which is not loaded yet so you get this error. also have a "," after the last entry in the resources array